Unable to stop "Record Espressor test" in android Studio
I am working with Android Studio Iguana, I started Record Espresso Test and after selection all steps when I tap on OK it is not stopping I'm not sure what to do.
I have a multi-modular project on kotlin/java & XML.
:app : packageName: com.app.main
:presentation (UI) : packageName: com.presentation.main

I tried to record a kind of macro test and recorded all steps. Seeing tutorials I found on pressing OK button it will stop recording and ask you to name file but nothiung happening.
Logs only shows action cancel

